# How to count all records linked to an id with codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I'm making a function where I need to display to the user the total amount of properties in the enterprise X

Doing this only with PHP was very easy, but how do I do this function in codeigniter 3

`SELECT * FROM "ci_properties" WHERE "business_id" = 130`

This is my controller `Empreendimentos.php`

```
public function index()
{   

    $lista = $this->empreendimentos_model->getEmpreendimentos();
    $dados = array("empreendimentos" => $lista);
    
    $dados['view'] = 'empreendimentos_list';
    $dados['count_empreendimentos'] = $this->empreendimentos_model->countEmpreendimentos();

    $dados['count_imoveis_emp'] = $this->empreendimentos_model->countImoveisEmpreendimentos();

        $this->load->view('empreendimentos_list', $dados);

}
```

And this is my model with a function `countImoveisEmpreendimentos`

```
public function countImoveisEmpreendimentos($empreendimento_id)
{

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('ci_properties');
  $this->db->where('empreendimento_id', $empreendimento_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();        
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

And here I will list the total amount of properties in the listed development

```
<li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 110px;"><a href="#"><?= $count_imoveis_emp; ?> imóveis</a></li>
```

In short, I want to do this, display the total amount of real estate in each development.

[image]